# Aggregrate dataframe having different ID's with same timestamp value

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have a dataframe that has two different ID's with same `event_time`. I am supposed to aggregate this dataframe to 1 hour and take mean value of remaining columns,

```
       id          event_time  1  2  3  4 33 34   38      39   41   42
1     1001 2017-05-22 16:56:07 NA NA NA NA NA NA   NA 1215.35   NA   NA
2     1001 2017-05-22 16:57:07 NA NA NA NA NA NA 53.5 1243.36 0.24 0.20
3     1001 2017-05-22 16:58:07 NA NA NA NA NA NA 53.8 1234.08 0.71 0.88
4     1001 2017-05-22 16:59:07 NA NA NA NA NA NA 53.2 1236.73 0.55 0.42
5     1001 2017-05-22 17:00:08 NA NA NA NA NA NA 53.8 1257.87 0.43 0.36
6     1001 2017-05-22 17:01:08 NA NA NA NA NA NA 52.8 1222.55 0.78 0.42
 ....
        id          event_time  1  2  3  4 33 34   38      39   41   42
95     1002 2017-05-22 16:56:50 NA NA NA NA NA NA   NA 1220.35   NA   NA
96     1002 2017-05-22 16:57:07 NA NA NA NA NA NA 53.5 1233.36 0.24 0.20
97     1002 2017-05-22 16:58:17 NA NA NA NA 44 NA 53.8 1256.08 0.71 0.88
98     1002 2017-05-22 16:59:33 NA 11 NA NA NA NA 53.2 1277.73 0.55 0.42
99     1002 2017-05-22 17:00:21 NA 11 NA NA 56 NA 53.8 1288.87 0.43 0.36
100    1002 2017-05-22 17:01:10 NA 19 NA NA NA NA 52.8 1201.55 0.78 0.42
```

I used dplyr package to use `group_by` for ID's and then aggregate. But it throws error

```
data_1hour <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% aggregate(list( Tag_1 = data$`1`, Tag_2 =  data$`2`,
                                              Tag_3 = data$`3`, Tag_4 = data$`4`,
                                              Tag_33 = data$`33`,Tag_34 = data$`34`,
                                              Tag_38 = data$`38`,
                                              Tag_39 = data$`39`,Tag_40 = data$`41`,
                                              Tag_42 = data$`42`),
                                         list(timestamps = cut(data$event_time, "1 hour")),mean, na.rm = "TRUE")
```

> Error in match.fun(FUN) :    'list(timestamps = cut(data$event_time,
>   "1 hour"))' is not a function, character or symbol

I have too many NA values and would like to ignore it and so i used `na.omit = true`. How do i proceed with this?

Comment: first your aggregate syntax is wrong, second don't use aggregate together with dplyr. try `summarise`.

Comment: `data_1hour <- data %>% group_by(assetid) %>% summarise(Tag_1 = mean(data[,3]),Tag_2 = mean(data[,4]),
                                                       timestamps = cut(data$event_time, "1 hour"))`  this doesn;t work. How do i cut my timestamp to one hour using summarise function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate by hour by first extracting the day and the hour and then aggregating according to this new variable. It could look something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

## Some sample data:
data <- data.frame(
        id = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L),
        event_time = c("2017-05-22 16:56:07", "2017-05-22 16:57:07", 
                "2017-05-22 16:58:07", "2017-05-22 16:59:07", "2017-05-22 17:00:08", 
                "2017-05-22 17:01:08"), 
        `1` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `2` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `3` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `33` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `34` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `38` = c(NA, 53.5, 53.8, 53.2, 53.8, 52.8), 
        `39` = c(1215.35, 1243.36, 1234.08, 1236.73, 1257.87, 1222.55), 
        `41` = c(NA, 0.24, 0.71, 0.55, 0.43, 0.78), 
        `42` = c(NA, 0.2, 0.88, 0.42, 0.36, 0.42)) %>% 
    setNames(c("id", "event_time", "1", "2", "3", "4", "33", "34", "38", "39", 
                "41", "42")) 

## Aggregate by hour and compute mean values:
hourlyMeans <- data %>% dplyr::mutate(dayHour = substr(event_time, 1, 13)) %>%
        dplyr::group_by(id, dayHour) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(Tag_3 = mean(`3`, na.rm = TRUE),
                Tag_33 = mean(`33`, na.rm = TRUE),
                Tag_38 = mean(`38`, na.rm = TRUE),
                Tag_39 = mean(`39`, na.rm = TRUE),
                Tag_42 = mean(`42`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Here is the result:

```
# # A tibble: 2 x 7
# # Groups:   id [?]
#      id       dayHour Tag_3 Tag_33 Tag_38  Tag_39 Tag_42
#   <int>         <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  1001 2017-05-22 16   NaN    NaN   53.5 1232.38   0.50
# 2  1002 2017-05-22 17   NaN    NaN   53.3 1240.21   0.39
```

Comment: Thanks but you could see i have two id's (1001 and 1002) . so i tried this, but it doesnt result what i need,  `hourlyMeans <- data %>% group_by(id) %>%  dplyr::mutate(dayHour = substr(event_time, 1, 13)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(dayHour) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Tag_3 = mean(`3`, na.rm = TRUE),
                   Tag_33 = mean(`33`, na.rm = TRUE),
                   Tag_38 = mean(`38`, na.rm = TRUE),
                   Tag_39 = mean(`39`, na.rm = TRUE),
                   Tag_42 = mean(`42`, na.rm = TRUE))` This results in adding all the hours of 1001 and 1002 id's and not separately

Comment: have updated the answer